# How to print custom error message?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have the following Discord bot which sends a private message to a specific user, but if the user has disabled direct messaging on server I get the following error in cmd:

> discord.errors.Forbidden: FORBIDDEN (status code: 403): Cannot send
>   messages to this user

How can I amend the code so that I get a custom message instead of the above error, for example "Unable to message this user"

I have googled but unable to find a solution.

**Here is the current code:**

```
import discord
import asyncio
import os
from users import userID

key = open("ID.txt","r").readline()
message = open("message.txt","r").read()

bot = discord.Client() # Assign client to an easier variable to follow... for fun.

@bot.event  # must confirm the connection when it's done connecting
async def on_ready():
    print("Connected!")
    print("Username: " + bot.user.name)
    print("   ")
    user = await bot.get_user_info(userID)
    await bot.send_message(user, message)
    print("Done")

bot.run(key.strip())
```

Comment: read exception handling

Comment: surround `await bot.send_message(user, message)` with a `try-except` block

Comment: @JayShankarGupta, I did and I don't understand it

Comment: @RompelSt0mpel https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions If you have a specific question about what the docs explain you can ask it, but at least try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `try`- `except` block, with the optional `else` keyword.

```
try:
    user = bot.send_message(user, message)
except discord.errors.Forbidden:
    print(“User doesn’t allow direct messaging.”)
else:
    print(“Done”)
```

What this does is: It tries to send the message to the user. If it fails, and receives a `discord.errors.Forbidden` exception, it goes into the `except` block, and prints the message telling that it was forbidden. If it doesn’t get an exception, it goes into the `else` block, and prints done.